# display depth of stimulus (front, back, behind in front)

Tags: psychopy

According to http://www.psychopy.org/api/visual/textstim.html '`depth`' is now deprecated and *'Depth is now controlled simply by drawing order.'*

I'm using Builder 1.80.06 and have most stimuli defined in Routine dialogs but I need to draw some at runtime using code and I want them to go behind the other stimuli but can't work out how to do this.

Is there any way this can be done now?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**: given the new details, I believe that Jon's answer is the correct one.

**OLD ANSWER:** Since 1.72.00, the order of drawing in Builder is controlled by their order in the rutine. The topmost component is drawn first, then then the second on top and so on. The bottom component is always on top.

The order of components in a routine can be changed by right-clicking on a component to bring up a contextual menu with items like "move up", "move down", "move to top", etc.

As a side note: in code, the drawing order is simply the order of the lines of code:

```py
background.draw()
stim.draw()  # on top of background
fixationCross.draw()  # on top of the other.
win.flip()  # show it
```

You can verify that Builder does exactly this by looking at the python code it generates.

Comment: There was a [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5232894) concerning changing order of components, which got rejected. It should have been a comment so that you, @Jonas, could edit it in. Posting the link here in order not to lose the valuable comment.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot have made myself clear in my post (below) I'm NOT trying to create a dialog box. I simply want to display a polygon, drawn in a Builder code module BEHIND a polygon created in a Builder routine. It seems that ALL gui created components are always created before ANY components that are created in code, irrespective of timeflow.

Comment: You CAN change the order of components by right-clicking and selecting "move up" or "move down"

Comment: Oh, thanks for correcting, Jon! I've edited the answer, simply accepting the edit that Michael MacAskill made.

Comment: Thanks for the tips which are useful. I think however that it is currently impossible to display ANY stimulus that is created IN CODE behind a stimulus that is created as a normal component using the BUILDER dialogs, irrespective of where you place it, even if its on the 'Begin Experiment' tab on a routine that is earlier in the flow.

Answer (score 1):

The Code Component code really is inserted in order, as well as the code form standard components. The order of code *in different Routines* during creation is unspecified (you don't have control over which Routine's "Begin Experiment" code is executed first) but this doesn't affect your drawing depth anyway.

The key is that in your Routine the code in the "Every Frame" section, with the draw() command, has to be in the right order (before your standard components).